# Regex for enforcing a string contains English letters AND numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression for accepting strings of 8 characters composed of both letters and numbers, and not only letters or numbers.

The regex `'^[A-Z0-9]{8}$'` is not enough as it allows words like `'ABCDEFGH'` or `'12345678'`. How do I create a regex to only accept 8 character strings containing both capital letters AND numbers like `'AB123C7Q'`?

Comment: why regex instead of a simple check? are you asking for curiousity or planning to use this logic somewhere? this really isnt a task for regex.

Comment: Use lookahead: `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8}$`

Comment: @anubhava your regex solved the problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add 2 conditions (assertions) in your regex in the form of [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8}$
```

There are 2 lookahead assertions being used here:

- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`: Asserts that we have at a  letter ahead
- `(?=.*\d)`: Asserts that we have at last a digit ahead

Answer (score 0):

The following is an alternative for *Python* community presenting a much faster *pythonic* solution using builtin `str.isalnum` and `str.isdigit` functions:

Custom function called `checkalnum` (*"check if string contains alphanumeric"*):

```
def checkalnum(test_str: str):
    if not test_str.isalnum() or len(test_str) != 8:
        return False

    has_digit, has_letter = False, False
    for c in test_str:
        if c.isdigit(): has_digit = True
        else: has_letter = True

        if has_digit and has_letter:
            return True
    return False
```

---

Time performance comparison (in *IPython* session):

```
In [811]: test_str = 'AB123C7Q'

In [812]: %timeit re.search(r'^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8}$', test_str)
1.88 µs ± 284 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [813]: %timeit checkalnum(test_str)
992 ns ± 87.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [814]:
```